# Laravel Getting an error Undefined offset: 3

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting an error in my laravel application. The error states that Undefined offset:3.

Controller

```
        public function updateVisaDocuments($type, $details, $visa, $documents_id){
    $visas_documents_db = \App\VisaDocuments::where ( 'visa_id', $visa->id )->get();
    foreach($visas_documents_db as $document_db){
        $count=0;
        for($j = 0; $j < sizeof ( $documents_id ); $j ++) {
            if($document_db->id==$documents_id [$j]){
                $count++;
            }
        }
        if($count==0)
            $document_db->delete();
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof ( $type ); $i++) {
        if(!empty($type[$i])){
            if(!empty($documents_id[$i])){
                $visa_documents = \App\VisaDocuments::where ( 'id', $documents_id[$i] )->first ();
            }else{
                $visa_documents=new VisaDocuments();
                $visa_documents->id=Uuid::generate ();
            }
                $visa_documents->type=$type[$i];
                $visa_documents->details=json_encode($details);
                $visa_documents->visa_id=$visa->id;
                if(!empty($documents_id[$i]))
                    $visa_documents->update();
                else
                    $visa_documents->save();
        }
    }
}
 foreach ($visa->documents as $documents){
    $i++;
    $det=json_decode($documents->details,true);
    $size_det=sizeof($det);
    $size_det_inside=sizeof($det[$i]);
    $k=0;
```

View

```
<?php $size_det_inside = sizeof($det[$i]);?>
@for($j=0; $j< $size_det_inside; $j++)
@if($det[$i][$j] != '')
<input type="text" name="document_details[{{$i}}][]" value="{{$det[$i][$j]}}" />

@endif
@endfor
```

I am getting error here `sizeof($det[$i]);`  (View). I guess, the result is in json format and in my view file i am treating it as variable.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: You don't show us your `$i` variable before `foreach`

Comment: please post your full controller function :)

Comment: I have posted the controller function

Comment: `$i` should be reset `$i = 0;` before foreach it become undefined offset because you didn't reset it

Comment: Or can i add an exception or bypass the error?

Answer (score 0):

If your php version is 7.0 or above, you should use count() function instead of sizeof(). Please use count().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php